# Hex-Value in Visual Basic

Tags: vb6, asp-classic, vbscript

Can someone just help me refresh my mind?

How do you specify hex values in a Visual Basic 6 / VBScript Source?

It's not **0x**ABCD as it is in C++, that's what I can remember... It was something similar... But what?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try **&H**ABCD, that's how it works for most BASIC languages.

Comment: No problem. I always knew using PowerBasic for DOS would be useful for something ;)

Answer (score 9):

`VBScript` \ `VBA` \ `VB6` (and lower):

```
Dim MyValue As Integer
MyValue = &h1234
```

`VB (.NET Framework)`:

```
Dim MyValue As Integer = &h1234
```

Versions are usually backwards compatible syntax-wise, you cannot always use newer syntax in older versions.

Answer (score 4):

`&H<hex-value>` if my memory serves my correctly.

Like: `&HABCD`

Answer (score 0):

msgbox hex(255)

Comment: No, the other way around. For example if I want to assign a hex-value to a variable, not to encode an integer to a hex string.