# VBscript, what is mean "Const VARIABLE = &h3&"

Tags: syntax, vbscript, initialization

As described in the title, I am confused by such initialization as "&h3&". What does this mean? Thank you very much.

Comment: Without the `&` at the right side, `&h3` is a hex number (see [hex value in Visual Basic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428643/hex-value-in-visual-basic) - the syntax is the same in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declares a long variable with the value `3`.  Here's a quick break down of the syntax

- `&h`: In VB this is the prefix which indicates a hexadecimal number.  It's the equivalent of `0x` in C / C++ / C#
- `3`: The number 3 which is still just 3 when evaluated as a hexadecimal number
- `&`: Specifies it should be a long vs normal integral value