# assign hex values to variables according to its data types in visual basic .net

Tags: vb.net

I'm aware that my question is similar with this question: [Hex-Value in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428643/hex-value-in-visual-basic)

but what I want to ask is a little more detail. My question is:

how do I assign a hex value to a variable according to it's data type in VB?
for example these are ways to assign hexes that i know:

```
Dim arr_ui as UInteger() = {&HABCDEF01UI, &HABCDEF01UI} '32 bit unsigned integer
Dim arr as Integer() = {&HABCDEF01, &HABCDEF01}         '32 bit signed integer
Dim arr_64 as Int64() = {&HABCDEF01&, &HABCDEF01&}      '64 bit signed integer
```

so that brings back to my question, how to assign these hexes:
- unsigned 64 bit integer
- signed and unsigned 16 bit integer
- signed and unsigned 8 bit integer

thanks in advance

Comment: Your answer is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx.  Note the difference between suffixes that are intended for variables and those that are intended for literals.  The literal suffixes don't change whether using decimal, hexadecimal or octal literals.

Comment: wow @jmcilhinney thanks, that is exactly what i want to know, i did not find it cause i didnt know what was the word for it, thanks and consider to post your comment as an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since jmcilhinney does not want to claim his credit, the answer is here folks https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx

here are some examples:

```
Dim a As Short = &H8000S    -- 16 bit signed
Dim b As UShort = &H8000US  -- 16 bit unsigned
Dim c As Short = &H8000I    -- 32 bit signed
Dim d As UShort = &H8000UI  -- 32 bit unsigned
Dim e As Short = &H8000L    -- 64 bit signed
Dim f As UShort = &H8000UL  -- 64 bit unsigned
```

alternate method:

```
Dim g As Short = &H8000%    -- 32 bit signed
Dim h As Short = &H8000&    -- 64 bit signed
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @tunaki, sorry did not consider that MSDN would scrap the content someday, you are right though.

Answer (score 0):

```
' unsinged 64 bit integer
Dim uLong As ULong = &H123UL

' singed and unsigned 16 bit integer
Dim uShort As UShort = &H123US
Dim sShort As Short = &H123S

' signed and unsiged 8 bit integer:
' byte and signed byte won't have a suffix in VB.NET.
Dim aByte As Byte = &H12
Dim aSByte As SByte = &H11
```

Comment: well, sorry JanR, this answer should be credited to @jmcilhinney as his/her comment answer my question more completely and he commented before your answer. And, is there any mods here? i like to request to close my question please.

Comment: My main intention was to remove your question from the list of unanswered questions for VB.NET. With my correct answer, I archived that. And yes, you’re right @jmcilhinney commented earlier by referencing the MSDN. But a single comment does not help anyone looking at the search results to recognize that this question contains a valid solution.